# Synonyms for 'entitled'?

Tags: synonyms

Looking for synonyms of 'entitled'. The dictionary lists synonyms for 'entitle' which has got to do with rightful access/privilege. I am looking for synonyms of the word in the sense of presuming (undeserved) privilege, as in entitled teenagers.

Edit:
I am not looking for a synonym in the context of teenagers necessarily –  sorry if the example implied that – just another word which means the same. The reason I want a synonym is that 'entitled', in the sense I want to use it, might not make sense to non-native speakers who might consider being 'entitled' a positive thing.

Edit2:
Have decided to go with 'acting entitled', which preserves the negative context for someone who might not understand that in the modern sense the word 'entitled' alone very often means that.

To people who never quite understood what I meant, consider the sentences:

1) He's the CEO – he's entitled to a larger office.

2) Millennials are such an entitled generation.

The difference should be obvious. The latter usage has become more popular, almost implied by default, in modern usage. Of course, the context makes things obvious. But for my purposes, I wanted the word to stand on its own and not be open to interpretation. Hence.

Comment: Self-important?

Comment: [brazen, overconfident, arrogant, egotistical, overbold, bold, audacious, pert, forward, familiar, impertinent, fresh, free, insolent, impudent, cocksure; cheeky, rude, impolite, uncivil, bumptious; overhasty, hasty, premature, previous, precipitate, impetuous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/presumptuous). We'd need far more than just **presumptive of privilege, as in entitled teenagers** to even *start* to narrow the field.

Comment: "Entitled teenagers" is already a shortened working version of what is really happening in that there is a large group of young people whom have a sense of entitlement.  I think @FumbleFingers almost has it pegged, though...it's a presumption of privilege, IMO.

Comment: I would say "*aggressive* presumption of privilege"...

Comment: Unfortunately, "entitled" has a dozen different definitions, some quite technical and specific to certain businesses.  Without a specific context it's impossible to provide a better definition than what the dictionary provides.

Comment: @Marv Mills: It's entirely your opinion whether *aggressive* is a more relevant factor than, say, *unthinking*, or *selfish* in OP's context. And personally I can't see *anything* in the subsequent edit that gives us any more information about the specific behaviour/attitude OP wants to identify.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Of course it is just my opinion, that should be clear from the way I posted it. I believe, judging from your own comments, that this new usage of the word 'entitled' has not crossed your path yet. I do not need more context to understand what the OP means. Usage of 'entitled' in this way already carries a common meaning in my neck of the woods and in my experience 'aggressive' is an apt addition that characterises the behaviour referenced.

Comment: @Marv Mills: I just changed OP's *presumptive* to *presumptuous*, added the word *synonym*, and posted a link to the first list returned within a Google search. I'm not sure what you mean by *this new usage of the word 'entitled'* though. In what way is, say, [*The Entitled (2011)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1650535/) any different to earlier usages?

Comment: how about elite, favoured, or advantaged ??

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't watch an entire movie to try and understand your POV. However the synopsis of the film bears no resemblance at all to the emerging use of the word 'entitled'. This merely underlines to me that you haven't come across it. The behaviour is characterised by someone posturing as if they have certain common rights that transcend another's position and that the other is overtly and unfairly attempting to overrule those rights. It says nothing whatsoever about the actual level of real entitlement. Braying, vocal or strident may also effectively replace 'aggressive',

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that it is a shorthand term, gaining favour in certain quarters, for "they are acting with an inflated sense of entitlement", if that helps in any way?

Comment: [And I'm really tired of the entitled attitude the kids themselves have.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22tired+of+the+entitled+attitude%22) That's from 25 years ago, but I can't see that the *meaning* of the word there is any different to the way it's been used for centuries. The only thing that's changed is we've become more likely to publically complain about young people having such attitudes. I just don't see any "new" sense there.

Comment: Perhaps the new part is the use of just 'entitled' instead of 'having an entitled attitude'? The word stands alone in the "modern" usage.

Comment: Just close the damn question. :D I've decided to go with 'acting entitled' to preserve the negative context. The discussion here seems so pedantic. It is clearly obvious to some what I am asking, while others seem baffled. :D I guess internet forums tend to behave like that sometimes. Anyway, I'm satisfied with 'acting entitled'.

Comment: @HimanshuP Perhaps it's a pity this was closed, as I think there is another simple answer: "self-entitled". I recall hearing people use it more, years ago (but still hear it used sometimes), and believe it helped (along with "acting entitled" and "entitled attitude") as a bridge between what was indeed the older meaning -- rightful entitlement -- and the current common usage of "entitled" alone for the negative use. I agree with Marv's suggestion that originally, "entitled attitude" was a combination of the rightful sense with "attitude" -- with "attitude" being what indicated the presumption.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to go with an idiom, a common one is *spoiled*, or sometimes expanded to *[spoiled rotten](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spoiled+rotten).*

> That child's parents have spoiled her rotten.

It refers to a child that has been given in to and over-indulged, to the point of having a damaged sense of the value of the things or the effort required to obtain them.